# Sparql : Finding Leaf Uri's

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Let me know your thoughts on this..

**Goal:** To extract URIs (leaf URIs) of a label being passed.

Where a *Leaf URI* is defined to be a URI which has no disambiguates or redirect to another URI.

Below query works fine for all cases other than for one where the URI has a redirect and the redirected URI has disambiguates.

Query :

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?termURI ?redirects ?term ?disambiguates 
WHERE
{
  ?termURI rdfs:label ?term .
  OPTIONAL{ ?termURI <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects> ?redirects .}
  OPTIONAL{ ?termURI <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageDisambiguates> ?disambiguates .} 
  OPTIONAL{ ?redirects <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageDisambiguates> ?disambiguates .}
  FILTER((?term = 'Build ups'@en))
}
```

Any Idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Please remember to use the code formatting button when posting a question (the one with the `{ }`) on it for the code portions of your question.  It makes your question much easier to read and answer

Comment: Thanks, Will make sure to do this in future!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a `FILTER NOT EXIST` to achieve your goal like so:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?termURI ?term
WHERE
{
  ?termURI rdfs:label ?term .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS 
  { 
    { ?termURI dbpedia:wikiPageRedirects [] }
    UNION
    { ?termURI dbpedia:wikiPageDisambiguates [] }
  }
  FILTER((?term = 'Build ups'@en))
}
```

What this query expresses is that you want to eliminate any matches for which there is either a redirect or disambiguates links.

See [Filtering Using Graph Patterns](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#neg-pattern) in the SPARQL specification for more details on these syntax elements.